# MAE loss function used for classification

Tags: keras, loss-function

For my classification problem I want to use loss function used prettly for regression, such as Mean Absolute Error.
Consider "y_pred" and "y_true" are in one-hot-encoding, but for MAE i need them in real number representation.

In this first case I'me getting error: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

```
def AgeAccuracyRegularity(y_pred,y_true):
    
    mae_func = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()

    y_pred_ages = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)+1,dtype='float32')
    y_true_ages = K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)+1,dtype='float32')

    res = mae_func(y_pred_ages, y_true_ages)
    
    return res
```

But if I manipulate the result with no sense in this way

```
def AgeAccuracyRegularity(y_pred,y_true):
    
    mae_func = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()

    y_pred_ages = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)+1,dtype='float32')
    y_true_ages = K.cast(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)+1,dtype='float32')

    res = mae_func(y_pred_ages, y_true_ages)

    mae = mae_func(y_pred, y_true)

    return res-mae+mae
```

it works. I check output of classificator and bot "mae" and "res" in the the custom loss function and they are the same size and type.

Comment: It does not make any sense to do this, argmax is not differentiable as it is a discrete function. What is even the point of trying this?

Comment: I want to use a typical regression loss function, such as MAE, for a classification problem. For doing in this way I have to transform y_pred and y_true from one-hot-encoding representation in a number, otherwise MAE is calculated over the probability of belonging to a class of each sample, and not over the batch. Do you know another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For classification problem you should use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" loss function. MAE is intended to be used for regression problems.

Comment: I understand, but I want to customize my classification loss function. For doing that I have to find argmax of the network output (that is in one hot encoding), but it is obviously a not differentiable function.

Comment: Even "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" is using argmax in picking the truth and the prediction. From the web: " Instead of doing log operations on all y_pred and then dot with y_true, we can directly pick the probability from y_pred at the index provided by y_true. Then apply log operation. loss = mx.sym.pick(y_pred, y_true, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
loss = - mx.sym.log(loss, axis=axis)